# Not recognizing import declaration

Tags: java

The console is telling me it can't find the symbol "getCurrencyInstance()" when I know I properly imported java.text.NumberFormat

I removed some code so it wasn't quite as cluttered; this isn't my whole class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Kohls
{

    // initialization
    static Prompter prompter;
    static Calculator calc;
    static Operator operator;

    private enum cardColor
    {
        RED, BLUE, GREEN;
    } // end of enum Color

    private static class Calculator
    {
        public int getDiscount(int age, cardColor color)
        {
            if (age > 62)
            // senior discount
                return 20;

            if (color == cardColor.RED)
            {
                return 30;
            }
            else if (color == cardColor.BLUE)
            {
                return 25;
            }
            else if (color == cardColor.GREEN)
            {
                return 15;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public double getSalePrice(int discountPercentage, double price)
        {
            double salePrice = price - (price * (discountPercentage / 100));
            return salePrice;
        }
    } // end of class Calculator

    private class Operator
    {
        public void getPriceWithDiscount()
        {
            // prompts
            double price = prompter.getPrice();
            int age = prompter.getAge();
            cardColor color = prompter.getColor();

            // discount(s)
            int discountPercentage = calc.getDiscount(age, color);
            double salePrice = calc.getSalePrice(discountPercentage, price);

            NumberFormat fmt = new NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            String salePriceFormat = fmt.format(salePrice);

            operator.display(discountPercentage, salePriceFormat);
        }

        public void display(int discountPercentage, String salePrice)
        {
            System.out.print("You saved " + discountPercentage + "% on your purchase.");
            System.out.print("\nThe price of your purchase with discount is " + salePrice + ".");
        }
    } // end of class Operator

    public Kohls()
    {
        prompter = new Prompter();
        calc = new Calculator();
        operator = new Operator();
    } // end of constructor

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Kohls kohls = new Kohls();
        kohls.operator.getPriceWithDiscount();
    } // end of method main()
} // end of class Kohls
```

Answer (score 4):

This is syntactically incorrect:

```
NumberFormat fmt = new NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

You are not newing an instance of `NumberFormat`.  `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` is a method call, and hence can't be newed.

Since the method already [returns a static instance of `NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28%29), go ahead and drop the `new` keyword from the declaration:

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove new operator in the line. It is a static method and should be accessed in a static away. More over, NumberFormat is an abstract class and you cannot instantiate it as well.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do

```
new NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

for a `static` method. Do

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
NumberFormat fmt = new NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

should be

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

since `getCurrencyInstance()` is declared static.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `new` as `getCurrencyInstance()` is `static`

Change

`NumberFormat fmt = new NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();`

to

`NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();`